# the page isn't redirecting properly in php

Tags: php, firefox, redirect, header

when i login with a not admin user it get me that error

> the page isn't redirecting properly

this is the login.php page code

```
<?php

require_once ('session.php');
if($_SESSION['userdetail'] !=FALSE){
    header('location: home.php');
            exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head><title>Login</title></head>
<body>
<form action="checklogin.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr><td>UserName:</td><td><input type="text" name="user_name"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" ></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and this is the ckecklogin.php page code

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['user_name']) || !isset($_POST['password'])){
     header('location: login.php?log=error');
            exit();
}

if(empty($_POST['user_name']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
     header('location: login.php?log=error');
            exit();
}


require_once('includes/connection.php');
require_once('includes/book_functions.php');
require_once('includes/user_functions.php');
require_once ('session.php');

$user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
$user=  get_user_by_name($user_name);
db_close();
if(!$user){
    header('location: login.php?log=errusr');
            exit();
}
$password=$_POST['password'];
$user->passhash;
if (password_verify($password, $user->passhash)) {

    $_SESSION['userdetail']=$user;
    $_SESSION['userdetail']->passhash = NULL;
    header('location: home.php');
            exit();
}
else{
     header('location: login.php?log=errusr');
            exit();
}
```

it header me to home.php and firefox get me this error ,, this is if i login like a normal user but if i login with my admin account i works without any problems! 
what is the problem?

Comment: `$_SESSION['userdetail']->passhash` why you are using `->`? `$_SERVER` is an array not an object

Comment: it is $_SESSION not $_SERVER ,, i put my user object in the $_SESSION['userdetail'] so that it is converted into an object

Answer (score 1):

you should not have any output before headers sent

bad:

```
    print_r($_SESSION['user_info']);
   header('location: home.php');
```

good:

```
   header('location: home.php');
```

bad:

```
echo $password=$_POST['password'];
echo $user->passhash;
```

good:

```
"emptyness"
```

Comment: i put it to make sure that the login is right but it's the reason of the problem

Comment: you are welcome. just remember, u can use it for some kind of debug, but replace after. there should be NO OUTPUT BEFORE HEADERS SENT

Comment: thanks MR Fox Malder ,, i will put this In consideration :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ob_clean` to remove header errors also it's good to use `window.location` or redirection by javascript